# Show Image in Leaflet Popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, leaflet

I'm trying to get the weather icon to show in a map marker using wunderground's api, Leaflet and Cloudmade.  I've got the text showing and a variable with the icon image, but I'm not sure how to get it to show.  Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajax({
          url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/cd48ac26fb540679/conditions/q/pws:KCASANFR128.json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          success: function(parsed_json) {
              var location = parsed_json['current_observation']['observation_location']['city'];
              var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
              var icon = parsed_json['current_observation']['icon_url'];
              marker1.bindPopup("Current temperature in " +location+ " is: " + temp_f).openPopup();
        }
    });
});
```

I tried this with no success:

```
marker1.bindPopup( <img src=icon> "Current temperature in " +location+ " is: " + temp_f).openPopup();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The marker's bindPopup method just takes HTML content as a string, so you'll need to surround your  tags with quotes as well - something like

```
marker1.bindPopup( "<img src=" + icon_url + "/> Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f)
```

ought to work for you.

Comment: As of ES6 you can also [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for formatting