# Show image in Leaflet popup not working

Tags: javascript, image, popup, leaflet

I am trying to show an image in the a popup on a Leaflet map following [this example here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575765/show-image-in-leaflet-popup) I think I have the format set up the same but am not sure why it isn't showing.

What am I doing wrong?

Example I am following:

```
marker1.bindPopup( "<img src=" + icon_url + "/> Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f)
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>DC Area Parks</h1>
            <p>Parks in the DC area that I have visited since creating this page.</p>
            <br>
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 100vh;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 5px gray;
    margin-top: none;
    padding-top: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#map {
    height: 300px;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("The JavaScript has loaded");
    var map = L.map('map',{ center: [38.907192, -77.036871], zoom: 9});
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap' }).addTo(map);
    //Potomac Overlook Park
    var potomacOverlookPark = L.marker([38.990175, -77.165271]).addTo(map);
    potomacOverlookPark.bindPopup("Potomac Overlook Park <br> The second line <br> <img src=" + images/PotOvePar.jpg + "/>");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, the `icon_url` is not a comment for you to paste the path to your image, but an example of variable which value is a string representing that path.

Therefore in your case you would do one of the following:

```
// Directly write your image src in the popup html string.
potomacOverlookPark.bindPopup("Potomac Overlook Park <br> The second line <br> <img src='images/PotOvePar.jpg'/>");
```

Or:

```
// Assign the path to a variable. Then it looks closer to your example:
var icon_url = "images/PotOvePar.jpg";
potomacOverlookPark.bindPopup("Potomac Overlook Park <br> The second line <br> <img src=" + icon_url + "/>");
```